# How to Randomized the questions and answer at once in quiz app multiple choices using Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

Here is the code of **Question and Answer**

```
public class QuestionAnswer {

    public static String[] question ={
            "Who invented C++ ?",
            "Which is not the programming language ?",
            "What is C++ ?",
            "Which of the following is the correct syntax of including a user defined header files in C++ ?",
            

    };

    public static String[][] choices ={
            {"Dennis Retchie","Ken Thompson","Brian Kernighan","Bjarne Stroustrup"},
            {"Java","C++","Notepad++","Python"},
            {"C++ is an object oriented programming language"
                    ,"C++ is a procedural programming language"
                    ,"C++ supports both procedural and object oriented programming language"
                    ,"C++ is a functional programming language"},
            {"#include [userdefined]","#include <userdefined.h>","#include “userdefined”","#include <userdefined>"},
            

    };

    public static String correctAnswer[]={
            "Bjarne Stroustrup",
            "Notepad++",
            "C++ supports both procedural and object oriented programming language",
            "#include “userdefined”",
            

    };
}
```

Here is the code in **Quiz**

```
public class Quiz extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView totalQuestion_tv, question_tv,score_tv;
    Button ansA, ansB, ansC, ansD, submitBtn,stopBtn;

    int score;
    int totalQuestion = QuestionAnswer.question.length;
    int currentQuestionIndex = 0;
    String selectedAnswer = "";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);


        totalQuestion_tv = findViewById(R.id.total_question);
        question_tv = findViewById(R.id.question);
        score_tv = findViewById(R.id.my_score);

        ansA = findViewById(R.id.ans_A);
        ansB = findViewById(R.id.ans_B);
        ansC = findViewById(R.id.ans_C);
        ansD = findViewById(R.id.ans_D);
        submitBtn = findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
        stopBtn = findViewById(R.id.stop_btn);


        ansA.setOnClickListener(this);
        ansB.setOnClickListener(this);
        ansC.setOnClickListener(this);
        ansD.setOnClickListener(this);
        submitBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        stopBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        stopBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        totalQuestion_tv.setText("Total Question: "+totalQuestion);

        loadNewQuestion();
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ansA.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        ansB.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        ansC.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        ansD.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        Button click_btn = (Button) v;
        if(click_btn.getId()==R.id.submit_btn){

            if(selectedAnswer.equals(correctAnswer[currentQuestionIndex])) {
                score++;
            }
            score_tv.setText("Score: "+score);
            currentQuestionIndex++;

            loadNewQuestion();

        }
        else if(click_btn.getId() == R.id.stop_btn){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(" Quit Quiz ")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to quit ?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Quit",((dialogInterface, x) -> finishQuiz()))
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",((dialogInterface, x) -> loadNewQuestion()))
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .show();
        }
        else{
            selectedAnswer = click_btn.getText().toString();
            click_btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

        }

    }
    private void loadNewQuestion() {
        ranDomized();

        if(currentQuestionIndex==totalQuestion){
            finishQuiz();
            return;
        }

        question_tv.setText(question[currentQuestionIndex]);
        ansA.setText(choices[currentQuestionIndex][0]);
        ansB.setText(choices[currentQuestionIndex][1]);
        ansC.setText(choices[currentQuestionIndex][2]);
        ansD.setText(choices[currentQuestionIndex][3]);


    }
    void ranDomized(){
        //Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(choices[currentQuestionIndex]));
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(question));
        choices.equals(question);
    }

    void finishQuiz() {

        String passStatus = "";
        if(score > totalQuestion*0.60){
            passStatus = "Passed";
        }else{
            passStatus = "Failed";
        }
        score = 0;

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(passStatus)
                .setMessage("Score is: "+score+" out of "+ totalQuestion)
                .setPositiveButton("Restart",((dialogInterface, i) -> restartQuiz()))
                .setNegativeButton("Exit",((dialogInterface, i) -> finish()))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .show();
    }


    void restartQuiz() {
        score = 0;
        currentQuestionIndex = 0;
        loadNewQuestion();
    }

    void correctAns(){
        currentQuestionIndex++;
        score_tv.setText("Score: "+score);
        loadNewQuestion();
    }
}
```

```
void ranDomized(){
        //Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(choices[currentQuestionIndex]));
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(question));
        choices.equals(question);
    }
```

I'm trying this code to randomized the questions, The question is randomly generates but not the choices, **What I want is whatever the questions is, its choices will follow concurrently.**

*For Example:*
If question number 3 will generate the choices of question in number 3 will follow
How can I do that Please Help, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array that contains indexes and shuffle it. Then use those indexes to reference both arrays.

```
List<Integer> indices = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2);

Collections.shuffle(indices);

String question = questions[indices.get(0)];
String answer = answers[indices.get(0)];
```